# Galois group of $x^3-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group, splitting-field

As titled. Let $\omega$ be a primitive cubic root of unity. I find the splitting field $E$ of $x^3-2$ over $F=$ $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)$ is  $\mathbb{Q}(\omega,2^{1/3})$. Now I need to determine the elements in $Aut(E/F)$. I know that the automorphism is a subgroup of $S_3$,but I don't know exactly how to determine it. The identity automorphism belongs to $Aut(E/F)$.

If we consider $\sigma(2^{1/3})= \omega\cdot2^{1/3}$, then this is a subgroup which sends $2^{1/3}$ to $\omega\cdot2^{1/3}$, $\omega\cdot2^{1/3}$ to $\omega^2\cdot 2^{1/3}$ and $\omega^2\cdot2^{1/3}$ back to $2^{1/3}$. So this is a permutation of $(123)$ in $S_3$.

Similarly, $\sigma(2^{1/3})= \omega^2\cdot2^{1/3}$ is a permutation of $(132)$. Are these the only automorphism groups? If so, why can't $(13)(2) \ \text{or} \ (12)(3)$ be in $Aut(E/F)$?

Comment: By $(13)(2)$ presumably you  mean an automorphism that exchanges $2^{1/3}$ and $\omega^2 2^{1/3}$ but leaves $\omega 2^{1/3}$ invariant. What does this map do to $\omega = (\omega 2^{1/3})/2^{1/3}$?

Comment: It maps $\omega$ to $1/\omega$. This automorphism doesn't preserves $\omega$, so it is not an automorphism of $E/F$. Is that the correct explanation?

Comment: That's a correct observation. So you see that this cannot be an automorphism of $E$ of $F$. Of course, this whole thing just follows from Galois Theory: $\mathrm{Aut}(E/F)$ is the subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(E/\mathbb{Q})$ consisting of the automorphisms that send $\omega$ to itself.